# MySQL storing and searching for text

Tags: python, mysql, elasticsearch

Let say that we have around 3M document of one page each. I want to import all the text in a MySQL database. For what I'm reading, I can add it in as a text field (65535 characters).
My challenge is this, we are receiving documents on a daily basis that is slightly or identical to one of the 3M documents we have. Is there a way or structure that can search a block of text in MySQL text when the input text is not identical? I need to know if we have one or multiple documents that are closely matching the one received. In a perfect world, I would like to have a result of the one that is closer in match to the search text...

The resulting mechanism to do this could include MySQL and Python as a solution. I can't find anywhere what could be the best approach to do this and that doesn't take forever to search.

[Edited 2020-09-29]
From what I have found for the moment, it looks like a good direction for that type of problem could be to use Elasticsearch as sabik pointed out.

**[Edited 2020-12-14]**
We finally have given a try to ElasticSearch and it's definitely a good solution.
One thing that we found not perfect is the fact that we want to search in the documents but if no document is close enough we wanted to have a similar score and it looks like this is not how it work. It always returns a document and the score is irrelevant. We will probably compare manually the best match to the searched document to have our own similarity score.

Comment: I believe what you want to do is to search for a particular type of pattern in MySQL right? You can use the [REGEXP](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-regexp-function.php#:~:text=MySQL%20REGEXP%20performs%20a%20pattern,NULL%2C%20the%20function%20returns%20NULL.) function.

Comment: And yes. If you dont want duplicate data, you can just assign a [PRIMARY KEY](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/definition/primary-key%23:~:text%3DA%2520primary%2520key%252C%2520also%2520called,and%2520only%2520one%2520primary%2520key.&ved=2ahUKEwiM0aavso3sAhVQzTgGHd9fA-kQFjAOegQIBhAG&usg=AOvVaw1xqzoayJCIajRpA2EhGZi7) to that field.

Comment: *Is there a way or structure that can search a block of text in MySQL text when the input text is not identical?* No such built-in instrument. And I do not see the way to perform it on MySQL effectively because all algorithms which checks texts similarity are iterative or even recursive. Of course, there exists a lot of particular cases when some pre-searching may be effective enough. For example, you may divide text to sentences or paragraphs and store into some table the text ID and sentence/paragraph checksum, then calculate the amount of equal checksums per text.

Comment: For searching of text documents, you probably want something like Elasticsearch or Lucene or whatever is today's equivalent, rather than MySQL; dealing with text is its own speciality and a general-purpose database like MySQL may or may not be well suited to it.

Comment: Yes as sabik has pointed, you should definitely go with `elasticsearch` to get `similar` matches. `RDBMS` doesn't have the kind of `search` capability what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I tried to do something like this with MySQL and then I found SQL SERVER FILESTREAM.

I save the document in a field of binary type varbinary(max), which takes up less space and the search is very fast.

Maybe now you can see if MySQL has something similar to FILESTREAM, I haven't researched it recently.

Comment: From what I have read, FILESTREAM can't give me a similarity it can compare only identical documents.